# Locations on map after interrogation - MGS5

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

So I've interogated a few guys on a side quest (the blueprints) and it was fairly straightforward when looking at the map to see the intel.  There were big 'ticks'.

I'm now out in the wilderness, interrogated a few more which have all given intel, the map is marked as updated but I can't find out where these 'ticks' are.  It feels like I'm missing a very simple mechanic.

Comment: Did they give you blueprints this time as well or did they inform you of something else?

Comment: This time I interrogated all 3 at an outpost.  One gave location of vehicles, another a specialist location (the one I want) and the last one told of a mortar location.  I can't see any on the map.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### There are several diffent types of things that can be located from interrogating enemies.

- Blueprints
- Processed Materials
- Material Containers
- Specialists / Skilled Soliders
- Vehicles
- Mortars

**These are just the ones on the top of my head.**

Now, Blueprints and Processed Materials are marked as big 'ticks', quite hard to miss.

Material Containers are marked as a white square on the map, this also applies to mortars and other stationed weapons if I'm not mistaking.

Vehicles are marked as white circles on the map.

Specialists / Skilled Soldiers are marked as small yellow/golden dots on the map.

Here's an image with some of the markings on the map.

[image]

Comment: thanks!  Is there a filter to show only specialists for example?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no. However, the Specialist indicator blinks, so you can't miss it.

Comment: thanks!  I'm not sure what happened then as I've had two specialist intel but nothing on map / blinking.  i am mid mission so perhaps that's something

Comment: I think I must've screwed up or interrupted the process somehow.  Just did it again and there they are, shining glimmering beacons of improvements :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad this helped!

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience, it won't work unless the guy I just interrogated is still conscious. I interrogated him and immediately brought up my map and there it was.

The second I choked him out however the blinking dot was gone.

Comment: False, the blinking yellow dot next to markers only shows what was just added on the map, and as such will disappear if you open it again. The marker itself won't disappear.